# Como distribuir igualmente os itens de uma lista horizontal independente da quantidade dos mesmos?

Tags: css

O snippet abaixo está funcionando corretamente, dividindo a barra de navegação em quatro itens igualmente distribuídos na horizontal. Execute-o para observar. Porém não está como eu gostaria: o campo largura (`width`) de cada item da lista é `25%`, e isso só funciona porque há exatamente quatro itens na lista. Gostaria que o CSS mantivesse a distribuição igualitária dos itens independente da quantidade dos mesmos no HTML. É possível?

```css
* {
    border: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border-width: 0px;
    outline-width: 0px;
}

nav {
    background-color: #a9eaff;
}

nav ul {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

nav ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 25%;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}

nav ul li:hover {
    background-color: blue;
    text-color: white;
}

nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    color: white;
}
```

```html
  <nav>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Início</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ideias</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Tecnologias</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Demonstrações</a></li>
</ul>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso é bem simples de fazer utilizando [`display:flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex). Precisa de aplicar essa regra de estilo no elemento pai dos que quer distribuir, e depois define a forma como eles se alinham com a regra [`justify-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content).

No seu caso dá jeito ter:

```
justify-content:space-around;
```

Que distribui o espaço à volta dos elementos. Veja como fica:

```css
* {
    border: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border-width: 0px;
    outline-width: 0px;
}

nav {
    background-color: #a9eaff;
}

nav ul {
    /*display: table; - removido*/
    display:flex; /*flex aqui - novo*/
    justify-content:space-around; /*e distribuição de espaço aqui - novo*/
    width: 100%;
}

nav ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    /*display: table-cell; - removido
    width: 25%; - removido*/
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 100%;
}

nav ul li:hover {
    background-color: blue;
    text-color: white;
}

nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    color: white;
}
```

```html
  <nav>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Início</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ideias</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Tecnologias</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Demonstrações</a></li>
</ul>
  </nav>
```

Se tiver 5 elementos funciona na mesma:

```css
* {
    border: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border-width: 0px;
    outline-width: 0px;
}

nav {
    background-color: #a9eaff;
}

nav ul {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:space-around;
    width: 100%;
}

nav ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 100%;
}

nav ul li:hover {
    background-color: blue;
    text-color: white;
}

nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    color: white;
}
```

```html
  <nav>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Início</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ideias</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Tecnologias</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Demonstrações</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Outro link</a></li>
</ul>
  </nav>
```

A forma como os elementos se distribuem é controlada pela regra [`flex-direction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction) que por defeito é `row` e faz com que os elementos fiquem todos na mesma linha.

Comment: Muito bom! Só acrescentei `width: 100%;` nos itens de lista do segundo exemplo para o efeito ficar totalmente igual ao do snippet da pergunta (o link ficar maior que o comprimento do texto).

Comment: @Piovezan Sim tem razão, retirei quando estava a testar e esqueci-me de colocar de novo com a dimensão que interessa.